# How do you execute a program in Go and return to the parent process?

Tags: go, operating-system

Say I want to execute Vim from the program, open Vim, and then return to the Go program after I exit vim instead of exiting the entire process. How would I approach that? Is there a method to fork programs in Go? I cannot find an answer to this question in my searches.

Comment: Show the code that you tried.  Describe in more detail how the process exits and what you expected instead.

Comment: I have written several programs that execute an editor using os/exec and then continue. There is really no special code required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the standard `os/exec` package. Here's a basic example from the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec?tab=doc):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("tr", "a-z", "A-Z")
    cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader("some input")
    var out bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("in all caps: %q\n", out.String())
}
```

Once you have a `Command`, calling `Run` executes it and waits for it to complete, which sounds like what you need.

Comment: I tried that - sorry, should've mentioned that in my post - and it seemed to exit the process entirely when completed.

Comment: @JohnAllison: show a minimal code sample that demonstartes this behavior.